# How do I append a list to an existing dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to find dates 27 to 33 days apart from the starting date provided in the dictionary; however, I cannot append the new dates to the key-value combination pair. I keep getting an error that cannot assign to a function call. Any help would be appreciated.

```
dictionary_items = {"one": [20210101], "two": [20210202], "three": [20210303], "four": [20210404]}

dictionary_items = dictionary_items.items()

for key, value in dictionary_items:
    temp_var = []
    value = value[-1]
    temp_var.append(value)
    for date in range(20210101, 20210531, 1):
        x = (date - value) + 1
        if 27 <= x <= 33:
            temp_var.append(date)
            dictionary_items[key] = temp_var

print(dictionary_items)
```

Desired output :

```
{"one": [20210101, Date2, Date3], "two": [20210202, Date2, Date3], "three": [20210303, Date2, Date3],
 "four": [20210404, Date2, Date3]}
```

Comment: Although your goal is a little ambiguous for me, but your error is because you're trying to add items to dictionary's view! not dictionary itself. (`.items()` is a view object)

Comment: I got this error : `TypeError: 'dict_items' object does not support item assignment`.

Comment: In the future, please [show complete error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you redefined `dictionary_items` label to it's `.items()` and you are trying to add item to `items` view. It's a just a view object of the original dictionary, you should add items to the dictionary itself:

```
dictionary = {"one": [20210101], "two": [20210202], "three": [20210303], "four": [20210404]}

for key, value in dictionary.items():
    temp_var = []
    value = value[-1]
    temp_var.append(value)
    for date in range(20210101, 20210531, 1):
        x = (date - value) + 1
        if 27 <= x <= 33:
            temp_var.append(date)
            dictionary[key] = temp_var

print(dictionary)
```

output :

```
{'one': [20210101, 20210127, 20210128, 20210129, 20210130, 20210131, 20210132, 20210133], 'two': [20210202, 20210228, 20210229, 20210230, 20210231, 20210232, 20210233, 20210234], 'three': [20210303, 20210329, 20210330, 20210331, 20210332, 20210333, 20210334, 20210335], 'four': [20210404, 20210430, 20210431, 20210432, 20210433, 20210434, 20210435, 20210436]}
```

---

Those temporary variables can be removed:

```
dictionary = {"one": [20210101], "two": [20210202], "three": [20210303], "four": [20210404]}

for key, value in dictionary.items():
    for date in range(20210101, 20210531):
        x = (date - value[0]) + 1
        if 27 <= x <= 33:
            dictionary[key].append(date)

print(dictionary)
```

output is the same.